# Can I Use same AWS S3 bucket for 2 domains whilst using the cloudflare CDN

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

I am using AWS S3 bucket for storing and displaying the user upload image files.
My website name is `example.net` and as I want to use cloudflare CDN and show the image url path as `images.example.net` (as I want to mask the S3 url).
I created a S3 bucket with name `images.example.net` and mapped the CNAME `images.example.net.s3.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` as images.

So I am able to access the images using url i`mages.example.net/myPic.jpg`
Recently I got a new domain `example.com` (only the extension is different), and now I want to use the same S3 bucket example.net to store the files and the url needs to shown as `images.example.com/myPic.jpg`

If I create a new S3 bucket `images.example.com` , then I can do it, but I want to use the existing one only.

Is there any method to configure in cloudflare for that ?
Can I do it without creating a new bucket named images.example.com ?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using [virtual hosting](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/VirtualHosting.html) then you're limited to a single domain per bucket by using the domain as the bucket name.

The only options available to you are:

- Create a second S3 bucket with your other domain name as the CNAME
- Create a CloudFront distribution in front of your S3 bucket and specify both domains as alternative domain names. Then on CloudFlare use the CloudFront CNAME. Disable all caching to allow CloudFlare to handle all the CDN functionality.

Obviously neither are ideal for your scenario, however these are the options available at this time.

Comment: Thanks Chris Williams for the reply.
I am hosting website on AWS EC2 instance and AWS S3 bucket is used only to store used uploaded files.My current domain is www.example.net and what I want to achieve is display images.example.net for this I created bucket images.example.net and after updating the cname its working fine. But for my new domain www.example.com (only extension changes), if I create a new bucket images.example.com, it will work, but I need to use the same bucket images.example.net and URL should be images.example.com.
So without creating how can I achieve this ?